# Methodology doubt in work by gravity in fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I hope questions like this are allowed in this community.

Let's consider I have two Interconnected containers of radii r and 2r and I fill water in them at heights 3H and H respectively.

The question is to find the work done by gravity in equalizing the container.

I'm not looking for the answer, just the method. I don't know how to solve questions like this and haven't seen it either.

[image]

Comment: Are the containers cylinders standing vertically on the same level?

Comment: @Peter same level

Comment: And are they cylinders? With vertical axis?

Comment: @Peter yes I have also added a picture from the question.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question as originally posed did not specify the actual shapes, nor the relative heifgts of the containers. OP has since clarified, and Gert has already provided an answer assuming the two containers are cylinders standing vertically. I did not assume this, so the following answer is too general for the actual question. I leave it in the hope it may be useful to somebody.

The principle isn't too hard - you find the total potential energy of the water in the two containers before and after equalisation, then subtract the totals.

It is the application that will be difficult. I don't know whether your containers are spherical or cylindrical (oriented vertically or horizontally) or something else, just that a radius is meaningful. Hopefully you can find formulas for your shapes that give the volumes of segments and the positions of the centre of mass of the segments. In this case you can get the potential energy before equalisation using $U=mgh$ for each container, where $m$ is the mass of water in the container and $h$ is the height (above some fixed level) of the centre of mass of the water in the container. To get the water depths in the two containers afterwards you will need to write expressions for the water surface height and the total volume in terms of the two depths (which might not be the same as the bottoms af the tanks might be at different heights). Then you will need to solve for the total volume equalling the original volume, and the two final water surface heights being the same.

If you can't find formulas you will need to integrate, summing small elements $\delta m.gh$ over the two containers. Each tank's potential energy will be
$$\int\int\int\rho gz\space dzdydx $$
where $\rho$ is the density of the liquid, $g$ is gravity and $z$ is the height above some arbitrary level. The end-points of the integrals will depend on the actual shapes of the containers.

Comment: Nice point. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you sir ,this was very helpful .

Answer (score 0):

> The question is to find the work done by gravity in equalizing the
> container.

To find the work $W$, we apply the Law of Conservation of energy, in the absence of friction and other non-conservative forces:

$$W+\Delta K+\Delta U=0$$

Here $\Delta K=0$ because the velocity of the initial and final system is $0$.

So we need to find the *change in potential energy* of the system.

Initially your system has potential energy $U_0$, found from the Centers of Gravity $h_i$ (and using the floor $h=0$ as a reference point):

$$U_0=\pi r^2gh_1+\pi(2r^2)gh_2=\pi r^2 g(h_1+4h_2)$$

where $h_1=3H$ and $h_2=H$, so:.

$$U_0=\pi r^2g\times 3H+\pi(2r^2)gH=7\pi r^2 gH$$

Because of the [Law of Communicating Vessels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_vessels#:%7E:text=Communicating%20vessels%20is%20a%20system,to%20the%20same%20atmospheric%20pressure.&text=This%20process%20is%20part%20of,each%20vessel%20(hydrostatic%20pressure).), once flow is allowed, both vessels will end up at the same level:

$$h_1=h_2=h$$

$h$ can be found from the volumes (continuity equation):

$$r\times 3H+2r\times H=r\times h+2r\times h$$

$$h=\frac{5}{3}H$$

The potential energy of the system has been changed, so that:

$$\Delta U=U_1-U_0=2\times\frac53(\pi r^2H)-7\pi r^2 gH$$

$$\Delta U=-\frac{11}{3}H$$

This equals also the work $W$ done:

$$\boxed{W=-\Delta U=\frac{11}{3}H}$$